# Mute ANY sound of my page. How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, silent, mute

I have a simple doubt. I'd like to MUTE any sound from my page. Is there a javascript, jquery or something that set the volume on 0 automatically for a page? just mute it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Short answer.. no.  The browser cannot mute the system.  That is an operating system level function.

Curious, though, as to what would even prompt this desire?

Comment: well, I'm trying to "embed" a movie list from flickchart, by setting an iframe with my chart page. saddly, the source page has an autoplay ad, so when you access my page, even tho you can't see the ad, you HEAR the ad speaking. so muting my page would be a simple solution.

I just wanted a personal movie list, embeddable, with posters on it. can't find a way to do that :/

but thanks a lot james. I'll keep searching a way to do that

Comment: but Thanos, it's inside the iframe and the iframe's page is not mine :/ therefore I can't target from parent page

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding style="volume: silent;" to the  tag and see if that has any effect. Not all browsers will support that though, and it might work for anything but a speaking browser (i.e, not ordinary sound effects).